# How can we convert List<Character> into an Array char[] with Java 8

Tags: java, arrays, char, java-stream

A solution I came up with is to create a `String` from the stream elements.

Like this:

```
listChars.stream()
    .map(String::valueOf)
    .collect(Collectors.joining()
    .toCharArray();
```

How it can be done without converting into a `String`?

Comment: I suspect you would be better off using a CharBuffer or StringBuilder to begin with, instead of `List<Character>`.

Answer (score 3):

There's no separate flavor of primitive streams for `char` type, for that reason this conversion with stream **can't** be done in such a straightforward way like, for instance, conversion `List<Integer>` to `int[]` with `IntStream`.

To turn a `List` of `Character` into an array `char[]` using streams, you can use [`CharBuffer`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api//java.base/java/nio/CharBuffer.html) as accumulation type.

That would allow avoiding making unnecessary copies of the data (which would take place with `String` and `StringBuilder`) because `CharBuffer` gives you access to its underlying array via [`CharBuffer.array()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api//java.base/java/nio/CharBuffer.html#array()) (*in case when it's baked by an array*).

That's how we can create a *collector* based on a `CharBuffer`:

```
char[] result = listChars.stream()
    .collect(Collector.of(
        () -> CharBuffer.allocate(listChars.size()), // allocating the underlying array
        CharBuffer::append,                          // accumulating stream elements
        CharBuffer::append,                          // merging buffers in parallel
        CharBuffer::array                            // finisher function - extracting the backing array as a final action
    );
```